# Refresh another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, refresh

I have an application that sends web requests to a .php file that then creates a flatfile database with the web requested data. Another .php file loads the data from the flatfile and creates a mock css file loadout just outside of the php code. An HTML file then treats the .php file as a .css file.

Quick pseudo of the php that acts as css:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");

load stuff1;
load stuff2;
?>
p{font-size: <?=stuff1?>;}
h{font-size: <?=stuff2?>;}
```

Well, you get the idea right? Basically, what I want to do is to refresh the html file whenever this mock css file written in php is changed. The application that I'm using constantly is sending data to my first php file, and I want to refresh the html file whenever the mock css file is updated. Any ideas on how I can sync this up? I also don't know how to refresh an external page. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: One step further. If I could somehow update the css without refreshing the page, that would be a huge bonus too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a date or cache thing to check if the file is newer than it was before. You can check once a while with AJAX if the file is modified and if the result is true you can refresh your page with jquery or javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "URL_TO_FILE",
    type: "GET",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
    //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

Here is a link so you can change the css file.
http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-change-css-file-2/

Comment: Do you have any examples with AJAX?

Comment: I've changed my answer with an AJAX example

Comment: great suggestion of datecheck for refresh